# This UPDATE appears to be successful but is not

Tags: php, mysql

My update seems to be successful but for some reason when I check my database it is not updating anything. Here is what I have:

```
$status="Approve";
$reservation=$_POST['reservations'];

 for($i=0; $i < sizeof($reservation); $i++){
    $sql = "UPDATE res_list 
       SET Office_Approval_Status = '$status'  
       WHERE r_no = 'reservation[$i]'" ;
}
 $result=mysql_query($sql);

 //condition that check if inserting is successful
    if($result){
        echo " &nbsp Successful";
        echo "<BR><BR>";
    } else {
        echo "&nbsp Error";
    }
```

Now what happens is it displays that the update is successful but for some reason when I check my database it is not updating anything. The "Office_Approval_Status" is still pending. Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: Hi again @Fred-ii- haha. Where will I put that? in my else statement?

Comment: Right after your opening `<?php` tag. Plus, I just noticed too `WHERE r_no = 'reservation[$i]'" ;` missing a `$` in front of `reservation`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you and sorry man, I know that was a rookie mistake.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's working now but it's only updating 1 row. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: No problemo. Ask one of the guys below that gave answers. I hardly ever deal with arrays; I just hate them lol - Yet I tend to think you may need to use a `foreach`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `$` in front of your variable in the query.

```
WHERE r_no = '$reservation[$i]'"
              ^
```

Keep in mind that you are also vulnerable to SQL injection attacks and that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and should not be used in new code. Definitely escape any variables you are using in queries and seriously consider using prepared statements instead.

Comment: I wish I knew what that meant, I am just new to php/mysql. But thanks for the tip I'll certainly use that in the future! BY THE WAY THANK YOU!

Comment: @Gaston: if `$reservation` is an array, then since you are in string mode, you may need to wrap the whole thing in braces, thus `{$reservation[$i]}`, so that the variable is not interpreted on its own.